# Adicionar javascript a plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Registrei meu arquivo Javascript em meu plugin porém as funções de `click` e etc. não funcionam.

Registrei meu arquivo principal do plugin com a `action`:

```
function add_scripts_to_plugin()
{
     wp_enqueue_script( 'birthdate_celebrate_js', dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/assets/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts_to_plugin');
```

O arquivo Javascript:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails').on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

O plugin carrega normalmente e não apresenta nenhum erro no console nem no PHP, mas mesmo assim o `eventListener` de clique não é adicionado ao botão.

Comment: Qual o link do site para que eu possa visualizar?

Comment: estou desenvolvendo localmente mas o [link do repositório é essse](https://github.com/rafa-acioly/birthdate-celebrate)

Comment: Você tentou substituir a linha `$('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails')` por `jQuery('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails')` ?

Comment: Sim Wendell, dentro da função `jQuery` tanto faz escrever o nome ou usar o `$`.

Comment: O botão é adicionado à página depois do carregamento inicial?

Comment: Sim Ricardo, a função `wp_enqueue_scripts` coloca o script no footer após o carregando usando o `wp_footer()`

Comment: Na verdade o Ricardo queria saber se o botão em questão é incluído via algum outro script, ao invés de estar no fonte HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta [neste tópico do stack em inglês](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216879/how-to-enqueue-javascripts-in-a-plugin).

Para incluir o arquivo com `wp_enqueue_script` que seja um **plugin**, deve-se utilizar a função `plugin_dir_url` e não `get_template_directory_uri()`, pois esta função retorna uma URL que aponta para o tema atual que esta sendo usado.

Resolução:

```
function birthdate_celebrate_add_interactions_to_plugin()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'birthdate_celebrate', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/assets/js/birthdate_celebrate.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'birthdate_celebrate_add_interactions_to_plugin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu vejo duas coisas que potencialmente podem dar problema aí, mas nada garante que são elas. A primeira é usar `dirname(__FILE__)` ao invés de `get_template_directory_uri()`:

```
function add_scripts_to_plugin()
{
     wp_enqueue_script( 'birthdate_celebrate_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/assets/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts_to_plugin');
```

A segunda é colocar um evento de clique em um elemento que esteja na página desde o page load, e delegar ao botão:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    // troque 'body' por um outro seletor mais próximo, talvez um pai direto do botão que quer alcançar.
    $('body').on('click', '#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails' , function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: alterei para utilizar a função `get_template_directory_uri()` e apliquei o mesmo método no `js` e mesmo assim nada aparece, o interessante é que se eu chamar no console do navegador apenas `$('#...')` recebo um erro dizendo que `$` não é uma função, mas se eu usar `jQuery` funciona...tentei usar `jQuery` no arquivo e mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: No console vc não vai conseguir usar `$` porque o símbolo é definido antes pelo navegador mesmo. Se com `jQuery('#...')` funciona então resta saber se o arquivo está sendo corretamente carregado. Ele aparece certo na aba `network`?

Comment: ma aba `network` não consta nada com o nome que defini

Comment: Ele não aparece? Estranho. Faça um teste colocando logo no ínicio do arquivo `console.log('meu script incluído');` e veja se a mensagem aparece no console do Browser. Se não aparecer, verifique o nome e caminho do arquivo, podem estar errados.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto, fiz um teste numa página apenas com um botão com esse id e funcionou.

Veja se na hora que você tenta anexar o evento o objeto já existe, coloque antes uma instrução para imprimir o resultado de `$('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails')`:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    console.log($('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails'));
    $('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails').on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

Outra forma de fazer, caso o objeto seja incluído depois, seria assim:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
```

Comment: aqui ainda não funciona, estou usando o tema do woocommerce `storefront` só para constar a info.

Comment: tentou colocar o comando `console.log($('#birthdate_celebrate_send_mails'));`  para ver o que ele encontra, se encontra algo?

Comment: não aparece nada

Comment: Então o botão deve ser criado após o load da página. Aí você deve usar a 2ª versão minha ou do Ricardo, que são parecidas.

Comment: já tentei os 2 e nenhum funciona :/